# Custom Query Content Filtering

Tags: search, meta-query

The following code is working when i remove the  Meta_Query part. But when i want to implement and use the search form, i have pass search form variables to the $args wariable. This is when the problem comes . No content to display. No errors . Please Help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <?php wp_head();?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        if($_GET['make'] && !empty($_GET['make'])){
            $make=$_GET['make'];
        }
        if($_GET['model'] && !empty($_GET['model'])){
            $model=$_GET['model'];
        }
        //$model=$_GET['model'];
    ?>
    <form action="<?php the_permalink();?>" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="make" placeholder="Make"/>
        <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model"/>
        <input type="submit" value="save"/>
    </form>
    <?php
        $args= array(
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'posts_per_page'=>-1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'make',
                    'value' => $make,
                    'compare' => '='
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'model',
                    'value' => $model,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        );
        $loop=new WP_Query($args);
        while($loop -> have_posts()): $loop -> the_post();

    ?>
    <div>
        <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
        <label><b>Make</b></label> : 
        <?php echo types_render_field("make");?></br/>
        <label><b>Model</b></label> : 
        <?php echo types_render_field('model');?></br/>
        <label><b>Price</b></label> : 
        <?php echo types_render_field('price');?>
        <hr/>

    </div>
    <?php endwhile;wp_reset_query();?>

    <?php wp_footer();?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your posts are having `make` and `model` as a Custom Fields and you want to retrieve all those posts which are matching both the passed value for `make` and `model` Custom Fields. If that is the case then your code seems to be correct. It might be possible that there is no matching post is there so you are not getting any result. But if you wants to retrieve all the posts which are either matching `make` or `model` Custom Fields value then you might need to add `relation` parameter in `meta_query` as the default value for the `relation` parameter is `AND`. Below is how you can add `relation` parameter with the `OR` in code.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'make',
        'value' => $make,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'model',
        'value' => $model,
        'compare' => '='
    )
)
```

Check the following link get more details on using `meta_query` in `WP_Query`. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query